# Relation doesn't work on laravel pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I can't get relation to works in eloquent on laravel 4.1 using pagination

Here is my eloquent model

```
class Featured extends Eloquent {

    public function info()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }

}
```

Here is my controller

```
$products = Featured::paginate(20);
return View::make('featured')->with('products', $products);
```

Here is my view

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    {{ $product->info->name }}
@endforeach
```

I get ErrorException. Trying to get property of non-object

When I use

```
dd($product->info)
```

I got `NULL`

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your relationships are not set up properly.  Generally that's the case when I run into that issue.  If you use a BelongsTo instead of HasMany or something.  Check this article for reference: http://matthewhailwood.co.nz/visualizing-laravel-relationships/

Also you should eagerload your relationship before you paginate or you run the risk of hitting the N+1 problem.  You should do `Featured::with(array('info'))->paginate(20);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my relationship setup. The problem is the foreign key is not matched with eloquent method name. I should've been more thorough. Thanks!